# SimpleXML and Retrofit: model for response with only root element

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, simple-framework

We are working on an Android project with an XML API, using `RxJava`, `Retrofit` and `SimpleXML` to handle requests and responses. The root of the responses can vary beteween two types:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<response>
 <Element1>Integer</Element1>
 <Element2>Integer</Element2>
 ...
</response>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
 <Element1>String</Element1>
 <Element2>Integer</Element2>
</error>
```

Therefore we use an XMLPullParse to parse the different kinds of responses to different models with their accompanying elements, which works fine.

**MyResponse**: The super class, which combines possible `errors` and `valid` responses:

```java
public abstract class MyResponse<T> {
    public final MyError error;
    public final T data;

    protected MyResponse(MyError mError, T data) {
        this.error = mError;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public final boolean isError() {
        return error != null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyResponse{" +
                "error=" + error +
                ", data=" + data +
                '}';
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

**SessionTokenResponse**: Example for a `response` class which extends MyResponse

```java
public class SessionTokenResponse extends MyResponse<SessionTokenResponseData>{
    public SessionTokenResponse(MyError mError, SessionTokenResponseData response) {
        super(mError, response);
}
}
```

**SessionTokenResponseData**: An example class showing how we build the model

```java
@Root(name = "data")
public class SessionTokenResponseData {

    @Element(name = "Session")
    private String sessionInfo;

    @Element(name = "Token")
    private String tokenInfo;

    public String getSessionInfo() {
        return sessionInfo;
    }
    ....
}
```

**RestClient - foo()**: A method in our RestClient class to parse different kinds of responses. If it was successful, then the response will have `<response>` as root element, if not the root element will be of type `<error>`

```java
private final <T extends MyResponse, I> Func1<ResponseBody, Observable<T>> foo(final Class<T> cls, final Class<I> innerCls) {
    return new Func1<ResponseBody, Observable<T>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<T> call(ResponseBody responseBody) {
            try {

                final String xmlString = responseBody.string();

                final XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                parser.setInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), null);
                parser.nextTag();

                final String rootTag = parser.getName();

                final Serializer serializer = new Persister();

                if (TextUtils.equals(rootTag, "error")) {
                    final MyError myError = serializer.read(MyError.class, xmlString);
                    return Observable.just((T) cls.getConstructor(MyError.class, innerCls).newInstance(myError, null));
                } else if (TextUtils.equals(rootTag, "response")) {
                    final I data = serializer.read(innerCls, xmlString);
                    return Observable.just((T) cls.getConstructor(HuiError.class, innerCls).newInstance(null, data));
                }
```

But we have problems with one type of response, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
 OK
</response>
```

**Our question would be:** How can we build a model for this kind of response if it has no elements? We still need to be able to differentiate between other responses with a `<response>` root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a spontaneous idea, we found the answer by ourselves.
The response will extend the super class and will not contain any additional model class like my example class **SessionTokenResponseData**, but only a String:

```java
public class LoginResponse extends MyResponse<String>{
    public LoginResponse(MyError mError, String response) {
        super(mError, response);
    }
}
```

So we don't need to modify our manual parsing in the RestClient class method and it works fine.